Calculating the ARE of parameters
I have the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate, optimize
import random

def dose(t, y, b, s, c, p, d):
  target, infectious, virus = y
  return np.array([
      -b * target * virus,
      b * target * virus - s * infectious,
      (1. / (d + 1.)) * p * infectious - c * virus
  ])

def model(D, b, s, c, p):
  solutions = []
  for d in D:
      solution = integrate.solve_ivp(
          dose, [0, 5], y0=[1, 0, 0.01],
          t_eval=[2.8828828828828827], # used to be np.linspace(0, 60, 1000)[48]
          args=(b, s, c, p, d)
      )
      data = solution.y[2, 0] / 0.01950269536785707  
      solutions.append(data)
  return np.array(solutions)

b = 0.00001
s = 4
c = 4
p = 2000000
p0 = (b, s, c, p)

np.random.seed(20)
D = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
z = model(D, b, s, c, p)
s = np.ones_like(z) * 0.05
n = random.gauss(0,z*0.05)
zn = z + n

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
  model, D, zn, p0=[1e-5, 1, 1, 1e6],
  method="trf", bounds=(0, np.inf),
  sigma=s, absolute_sigma=True
)

# (array([1.98458777e-05, 3.39383754e+00, 4.55115392e+00, 1.00007348e+06]),
#  array([[ 8.35308599e-10, -3.25230641e-03,  3.73469971e-03,
#          -5.22169803e-11],
#         [-3.25230641e-03,  1.28672442e+04, -1.47634805e+04,
#           2.06436797e-04],
#         [ 3.73469971e-03, -1.47634805e+04,  1.69398903e+04,
#          -2.36868204e-04],
#         [-5.22169803e-11,  2.06436797e-04, -2.36868204e-04,
#           3.31209815e-12]]))

Dlog = np.logspace(-3, 3, 200)
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(D, zn, label="Data")
axe.semilogx(Dlog, model(Dlog, *popt), label="Fit")
axe.semilogx(Dlog, model(Dlog, *p0), "--", label="Model")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
plt.show()

I would like to calculate the ARE (average residual error) of the parameters in the ODE (b,s,c,p). How can I do this efficiently? For reference, this is calculated with the following where $\theta$ is the new guess and $\theta_i$ is the old guess.
I would like to read off the parameters from the graph:

What is theta in your code? What's are new and old guesses?

the code prints a normal graph and a graph adjusted with 5% error
